# Having trouble parsing JSON response from Wikipedia

Tags: java, android, json, gson

So I'm making an android app that searches the mediawiki api to get a short paragraph of information about certain famous people.

The idea is that you'll be able to enter any name and it will provide the information that the mediawiki api has on that name/person, but for now I'm just sticking with one name until I figure out how to parse the JSON correctly.

I need the extract field from this json response:
[JSON response](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=Frodo%20Baggins)

This is currently what I have, I think the problem is within the Query class, I just don't know what that class needs to make sure only the extract field is returned. When I run the program the output of the onResponse() method is just null. Thanks for any help.

Okay I made the changes that were suggested and this is my updated code:

```
;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

import java.util.Map;


public class game extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String ENDPOINT = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?    format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=Harry%20Potter";

private RequestQueue requestQueue;

private Gson gson;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    gson = gsonBuilder.create();
}

public void fetchPerson(View view)
{
    fetchPosts();
}
private void fetchPosts() {
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, ENDPOINT, onPostsLoaded, onPostsError);

    requestQueue.add(request);
}

private final Response.Listener<String> onPostsLoaded = new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        final TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        Page page = gson.fromJson(response, Page.class);

        text.setText(page.extract);

    }
};

private final Response.ErrorListener onPostsError = new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.e("PostActivity", error.toString());
    }
};
public class Root {
    String batchcomplete;
    Query  query;
}
public class Query {
    Map<String, Page> pages;
}
public class Page {
    int    pageid;
    int    ns;
    String title;
    String extract;
}
```

}

Comment: what is not working?post your log too

Comment: The code fully works with no errors in the log, the problem was that I didn't have classes for every object within the JSON data. I made the changes that Andreas suggested and I updated the code above as well, however I'm still not doing something quite right and the output of the onResponse is still NULL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I think the problem is within the `Query` class

You are correct.

The JSON data looks like this:

```
{
  "batchcomplete": "",
  "query": {
    "pages": {
      "23140032": {
        "pageid": 23140032,
        "ns": 0,
        "title": "Frodo Baggins",
        "extract": "Frodo Baggins is a fictional character in J. R. R. Tolkien's legendarium, and the main protagonist of The Lord of the Rings. Frodo is a hobbit of the Shire who inherits the One Ring from his cousin Bilbo Baggins and undertakes the quest to destroy it in the fires of Mount Doom. He is also mentioned in Tolkien's posthumously published works, The Silmarillion and Unfinished Tales."
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The root object has 2 fields: `batchcomplete` and `query`.

You try to parse to an object with these fields: `extract` and `title`.

Do you see the discrepancy there?

You need classes for all the objects, if you want to use Gson.

```java
class Root {
    String batchcomplete;
    Query  query;
}
class Query {
    Map<String, Page> pages;
}
class Page {
    int    pageid;
    int    ns;
    String title;
    String extract;
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

You need to parse the JSON into the `Root` object.

Example code:

```java
String json = "{\n" +
              "  \"batchcomplete\": \"\",\n" +
              "  \"query\": {\n" +
              "    \"pages\": {\n" +
              "      \"23140032\": {\n" +
              "        \"pageid\": 23140032,\n" +
              "        \"ns\": 0,\n" +
              "        \"title\": \"Frodo Baggins\",\n" +
              "        \"extract\": \"Frodo Baggins is a fictional character in J. R. R. Tolkien's legendarium, and the main protagonist of The Lord of the Rings. Frodo is a hobbit of the Shire who inherits the One Ring from his cousin Bilbo Baggins and undertakes the quest to destroy it in the fires of Mount Doom. He is also mentioned in Tolkien's posthumously published works, The Silmarillion and Unfinished Tales.\"\n" +
              "      }\n" +
              "    }\n" +
              "  }\n" +
              "}";
Root root = new Gson().fromJson(json, Root.class);
for (Page page : root.query.pages.values()) {
    System.out.println(page.title);
    System.out.println("  " + page.extract);
}
```

*Output*

```
Frodo Baggins
  Frodo Baggins is a fictional character in J. R. R. Tolkien's legendarium, and the main protagonist of The Lord of the Rings. Frodo is a hobbit of the Shire who inherits the One Ring from his cousin Bilbo Baggins and undertakes the quest to destroy it in the fires of Mount Doom. He is also mentioned in Tolkien's posthumously published works, The Silmarillion and Unfinished Tales.
```

Comment: Okay thanks for clearing that up! I added the classes you suggested, so does that mean that in the onResponse method I should be getting the extract string like this? `public void onResponse(String response) {
            final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

            Page page = gson.fromJson(response, Page.class);

            textView.setText(page.extract);

        }`

Comment: Because I ran the program and it is still outputting as null after I made those changes. You are definitely right, I just think I'm still doing something wrong.

Comment: The output isn't NULL anymore, its now outputting a blank string, or nothing at all. I think its outputting the string extract but it seems like its empty.

Comment: I said *"The root object has 2 fields: `batchcomplete` and `query`"*. Then I showed you a class named `Root` with those two fields. So, parse the JSON text into that class, so it can map the fields correctly. Is that so difficult to understand?

Comment: Okay I understand. No need to be condescending, thank you for helping.